# Python DNS lookup: How to format a type AAAA (ipv6) bytearray response

Tags: python, arrays, dns, hex, string-formatting

Given the name of a domain, type of record, and address of a DNS server the program must return the ip address of the given domain. The parse answer method presented in this code takes a python byte array as its parameter and is able to handle ipv4 responses.

```
 def parse_answer(self, msg_resp):
    length = msg_resp[msg_resp.index(0xc0) + 11]
    addr = msg_resp[len(msg_resp)-length:]
    address = ""
    for i in range(length):
        address = address + str(addr[i]) + "."

    return address.strip(' . ')
```

When the implementation is presented with a request for google.com in ipv6 format, Wireshark returns that the ipv6 address of the site is 2607:f8b0:4009:808::200e as well as the following byte array: [image: wireshark output]
The parse_answer method returns:
38.7.248.176.64.9.8.8.0.0.0.0.0.0.32.14

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How to format a type AAAA ipv6 byte array response in python